# Making grid lines opaque so just lat/long coords on map border using QGISGDALPERF?

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, grids-graticules

Can any one help me with adding graticules to my map? I have managed to add a lat/long grid over my map, however I want the grid lines to be opaque with just the lat/long coords on the map border - is this possible?

I am using QGIS 1.8

Comment: What method have you used to create the grid - there are many.

Comment: Our protocols can take some getting used to but this question looks like it arises from an [**unanswered question**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69786/how-can-i-add-lat-long-coords-to-the-border-of-my-map) that you resolved yourself.  It would probably have been cleaner to just edit (and thus revise) that original question while it remained unanswered, rather than spawning a new one.

Comment: Based on your other question, it appears you're really asking to make the grid lines invisible, not opaque.

Comment: Are you talking about a grid in Print Composer, or a vector grid in the "normal" canvas?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 1.8 there is no direct way of making the graticules transparent (they are already opaque - so I assume this is what you mean).  However, you can 'cheat'.  Change the Grid Type from line to cross and then change the size of the cross to zero.

In QGIS 1.9, as well as the no-size cross trick, there is a direct way of setting the graticules' transparency.   When you adjust the colour of the graticules you can set an alpha value. Setting it to zero will make the graticules completely transparent.